# How can I run .class files compiled by sbt assembly

Tags: java, scala, sbt, akka, sbt-assembly

I'm working on an Akka project in scala. I'm using 'sbt assembly' to compile into .class files in 'target/scala-2.11/classes'
Then I try to run with `java -cp xxx.jar:/Users/haoboxuxu/opt/scala-2.11.12/lib/scala-library.jar:. HelloWorldTestJNI` or `scala -cp xxx.jar:/Users/haoboxuxu/opt/scala-2.11.12/lib/scala-library.jar:. HelloWorldTestJNI`.
Both don't work.
I get...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/typesafe/config/ConfigMergeable
at HelloWorldTestJNI2$.testForJni(HelloWorldTestJNI2.scala:13)
at HelloWorldTestJNI2$.main(HelloWorldTestJNI2.scala:24)
at HelloWorldTestJNI2.main(HelloWorldTestJNI2.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.typesafe.config.ConfigMergeable
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
```

Even the `scala xxx.jar` don't work

Comment: The idea of assembly is to create a **JAR** that has everything bundled, why not just `java -jar target/scala-2.11/assembly-jar.jar`? Or if you want to manage the classes yourself like this was the early 2000, then why even using assembly?

Comment: Mainly because I Use Jni in my project. `java -cp "${CLASSPATH}:${SCALA_HOME}/lib/scala-library.jar:target/scala-2.11/xxx.jar" Main` works.